# Prolog: generate a set of all ground terms from a list of predicates

Tags: prolog

Given the following facts:

```
female(alice).
male(bob).
male(charlie).
lives(alice,oxford).
lives(bob,oxford).
lives(charlie,cambridge).
```

I want to generate the set:

```
[alice,bob,charlie,oxford,cambridge].
```

I know how to this for a single predicate:

```
?- setof(X, male(X), S).
S = [bob, charlie].
```

But I do not know how to generalise this. The aim is to query the program with a list of predicates:

```
f([male/1,female/1,lives/2]).
```

I tried to generalise the above 'setof' statements:

```
g(P,1) :-
  Atom = [P,X],
  Goal =..Atom,
  setof(X, Goal(X, Y), S),
  write(S).

g(P,2).

f([]).

f([H|T]) :-
  H = P/A,
  g(P,A),
  f(T).
```

But this did not work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. [Higher-order programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.4505) in Prolog can be achieved with the `call` or `apply` predicates. Here's a version with `call/1`, which is standardized by ISO:

```
get_ground_args(Goal, Args) :-
    findall(X, (call(Goal), Goal =.. [_|GoalArgs], member(X, GoalArgs)), Args).
```

Example:

```
?- get_ground_args(lives(_,_), Args).
Args = [alice, oxford, bob, oxford, charlie, cambridge].
```

Now to tie this in to your original setup, use `length/2` to generate the initial arguments inside a nested `setof`/`findall`:

```
all_ground_args(Preds, Args) :-
    setof(X, (findall(Y, (member(Pred/Arity, Preds),
                          length(GoalArgs, Arity),
                          Goal =.. [Pred|GoalArgs],
                          get_ground_args(Goal, GroundArgs),
                          member(Y, GroundArgs)),
                      AllArgs),
              member(X, AllArgs)),
          Args).
```

Demo:

```
?- all_ground_args([male/1,female/1,lives/2], Args).
Args = [alice, bob, cambridge, charlie, oxford].
```

(All of this will probably fail when a predicate has non-ground args.)