# Grounding head and body

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a software using SWI-Prolog where i have to find all the groundings of a predicate. In particular all the subtitutions that grounds the head and relative body supposing i can access independently head and body. Here an example of the behaviour i would like to obtain:

```
student(a).
student(b).
student(c).

play.

study(A):-
    play,
    student(A).

ground(Head,Body,Result):-
    % some code
    ...

?- ground([study(A)],[play, student(A)],R).
R = [
    [study(a):- play, student(a)],
    [study(b):- play, student(b)],
    [study(c):- play, student(c)]
]
```

And maybe generalize to:

```
dog(d).
dog(e).

study(A,B):-
    play,
    dog(B),
    student(A).

?- ground([study(A,B)],[play, dog(B),student(A)],R).
R = [[study(a):- play, dog(d), student(a)] ... ]
```

So, for the body, find all non ground variables, ground them and then ground the head variables. Basically find all the combinations. The problem is to manage the body...
Maybe i can use for instance `=../2`, `functor/3` and `call/1` but i don't know how to takle the body ([see this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150545/prolog-generate-a-set-of-all-ground-terms-from-a-list-of-predicates)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why in the examples you provide the goal is inside a list and you also provide the body.

The procedure in this answer takes a goal, gets a matching clause and then gets all the solutions (binding the variables on the way). It may leave some variable unbound if they are not grounded by the goal. Upon backtracking it may take other clauses that match the initial goal.

```
ground(Goal, Body, LGroundClauses):-
  clause(Goal, Body),
  findall((Goal:-Body), call(Body), LGroundClauses).
```

sample run:

```
?- ground(study(A), Body, LClauses).
Body = (play, student(A)),
LClauses = [ 
  (study(a):-play, student(a)), 
  (study(b):-play, student(b)), 
  (study(c):-play, student(c))
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note on the question and accepted solution that's a bit too long for a comment.

@gusbro writes (emphasis mine): "I am not sure why in the examples you provide the goal is inside a list and you also provide the **body**." I would also like to see a clarification on this point.

The ISO Prolog Core standard allows the `clause/2` predicate to retrieve clauses for *public* predicates. But most Prolog systems, with a notably exception being SWI-Prolog, only allow using `clause/2` to access clauses of dynamic predicates. Moreover, SWI-Prolog `protect_static_code` flag can be set to `true` to disable using `clause/2` on static predicates. This makes the solution non-portable (and possibly undesirable in a deployment scenario) unless the predicates are declared dynamic. A possible alternative, assuming that indeed the `Body` argument is bound in a `ground(Head,Body,Result)` goal, would be to *construct* the clause body using the list of goals. Something like:

```
ground(Goal, BodyGoals, LGroundClauses):-
    list_to_conjunction(BodyGoals, Body),
    findall(Goal:-Body, call(Body), LGroundClauses).
```

This would remove the requirement of calling `clause/2` and possibly making the predicates dynamic for portability. But does it make sense in your case?